# Python: I have pandas dataframe which has the same column name. How to change one of those?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have pandas dataframe which has the same column names. (column names are a,b,a,a,a)
Below is example.

[image]

Is there any way I can change column name only for 3rd column from the left by specifying column location? I found that there is a way to change column name by making a new list. But I wanted to see if there is any way I can specify column location and change the name.
Below is what I want.
[image]

Since I am new to programming, I would appreciate any of your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this work?:

```
column_names = df.columns.values
column_names[2] = 'Changed'
df.columns = column_names
```

Comment: As it turns out, you don't need to assign df.columns as df.columns.values returns a reference

Answer (score 0):

df.rename(inplace=True,columns={'3col':'Changed'})

Comment: @d swamy Thanks for the advice! I run this code but it did not change the 3rd column name as "changed"...

Comment: replace '3col' with the 3rd column name. columns takes a dictionary of the current column names and the new column name.